# Document containing 4 pieces of data. Wanting to take the name and amount and output total amount per name

Tags: java

i have a text file that has date/time, name, amount tipped, total tips

I am able to get it reduced to just names (In one arraylist) and amount tipped(in a second arraylist)

Now I'm trying to get it to where it adds up the amount tipped per person.

So if X tipped 10,20,30,40 it will output X tipped 100.

From Text file

```
Dec. 6, 2013, 8:31 p.m.  Tip from y
25  7687
Dec. 6, 2013, 8:30 p.m.  Tip from x
30  7662
Dec. 6, 2013, 8:30 p.m.  Tip from z
25  7632
Dec. 6, 2013, 8:31 p.m.  Tip from z
25  7687
Dec. 6, 2013, 8:30 p.m.  Tip from z
30  7662
Dec. 6, 2013, 8:30 p.m.  Tip from x
25  7632
```

Here is where I am at so far

```
import java.io.*;
import java.util.*;

public class TipTester {

public static void main(String[] args) {
    int lineNumber = 1;
    List<String> name = new ArrayList<String>();
    List<String> tip = new ArrayList<String>();
    String fileName = "C:\\Users\\David\\Desktop\\tips.txt";

    System.out.println("Reading text from file");

    try {
        FileReader inputFile = new FileReader(fileName);
        BufferedReader bufferedReader = new BufferedReader(inputFile);
        String line;

        while ((line = bufferedReader.readLine()) != null) {
            if (lineNumber % 2 != 0) {
                System.out.println(line.substring(line.indexOf("from ") + 5) + "\\");
                name.add(line.substring(line.indexOf("from ") + 5) + "\\");
            } else {
                System.out.println(line.substring(0, line.indexOf("\t")) + "\\");
                tip.add(line.substring(0, line.indexOf("\t")) + "\\");
            }
            lineNumber ++;
        }
        bufferedReader.close();
        name.add("-");
        tip.add("-");
    } catch (Exception e) {
        System.out.println("Error while reading file line by line: " + e.getMessage());
        }
    }
}
```

Comment: Where is the tip amount in the text file?

Comment: I have no clue what a Map is. Im still learning. It was a project that was a bit harder than I could handle.

The Tip amount is the 2nd line first entry
Dec. 6, 2013, 8:31 p.m.  Tip from y 25  7687
25 is the tip from y

Answer (score 0):

Instead of using two different lists. You can just use a map.

```
Map<String, Double> map = new HashMap<String, Double>();

while ((line = br.readLine()) != null){
    double tip = // get tip from line
    String name = // get name from line

    if (!map.containsKey(name)){       // if map doesn't contain name
        map.put(name, tip);            // put in the initial name and tip amount
    } else {
        double value = map.get(name);  // else get the current value from the map
        map.put(name, value + tip);    // put in the new value to the map
    }
}
```

Now your map contains names and total tips

**Edit:** If you're using two different lists, you want to keep the name and tips in parallel indices.

You could do something like this

```
ArrayList<String> nameList = new ArrayList<>();
ArrayList<Integer> tipList = new ArrayList<>();

while ((line = br.readLine()) != null){
    String name = // get name from line

    int tip = // get tip from next line

    if (!nameList.contains(name)){     // if list  doesnt contain the name
        nameList.add(name);            // add the name
        tipList.add(tip);              // add the tpi
    } else {
        int index = nameList.indexOf(name);       // else get the index of the name
        int newTip = tipList.get(index) + tip;    // get the tip amount + new tip
        tipList.set(index, newTip);               // set the tip amount
    }
}
```

Answer (score 0):

Without too much modifications of your code (introduced a [`Map`](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/7/docs/api/java/util/Map.html) and used `Integer` for tips):

```
package com.stackoverflow.so20560521;

import java.io.BufferedReader;
import java.io.FileReader;
import java.util.Map;

public class Tip {

    public static void main(String[] args)
    {
        int lineNumber = 1;
        Map<String, Integer> tipsByName = new HashMap<String, Integer>();
        String fileName = "C:\\Users\\David\\Desktop\\tips.txt";

        System.out.println("Reading text from file");

        try {
            FileReader inputFile = new FileReader(fileName);
            BufferedReader bufferedReader = new BufferedReader(inputFile);
            String line;
            String currentTipper = null;

            while ((line = bufferedReader.readLine()) != null) {
                if (lineNumber % 2 != 0) {
                    final String tipperName = line.substring(line.indexOf("from ") + 5);
                    System.out.println(tipperName);
                    currentTipper = tipperName;
                } else {
                    final Integer tipValue = Integer.parseInt(line.substring(0, line.indexOf("\\t")));
                    System.out.println(tipValue);
                    // here we store the tip in the map. If we have a record we sum, else 
                    // we store as is
                    tipsByName.put(currentTipper, (tipsByName.get(currentTipper) == null ? 0 : tipsByName.get(currentTipper))
                            + tipValue);
                }

                lineNumber++;
            }
            bufferedReader.close();
            System.out.println(tipsByName); // output the map
        } catch (Exception e) {
            System.out.println("Error while reading file line by line: " + e.getMessage());
        }
    }
}
```

This outputs

```
Reading text from file
y
25
x
30
z
25
z
25
z
30
x
25
{z=80, y=25, x=55}
```

Comment: Make sure you have tab between tip and total, if not replace the `\\t` by two spaces in the code